# UITapGestureRecognizer with webView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am working with `webView` and I want to do something when user click on `webView` for that I use `UITapGestureRecognizer` something like this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
let SingleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://rshankar.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)

    SingleTap.delegate = self
    SingleTap.addTarget(self, action: "SingleTap:")
    SingleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    SingleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    self.webView!.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(SingleTap)
}

func SingleTap(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
    println("touch detected")
    }
}
```

But It's not working for me so that later I try same thing this way:

```
    let aSelector : Selector = "UserTap:"
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    func userTap(tapgesture : UITapGestureRecognizer){
    println("user tapped")
    }
```

But It is not working for me.

Am I missing some thing please help me for this. Thanks In advance.

Comment: did you set the `webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` ?

Comment: by default its a true.